# c++ - swapping nodes using pointers in doubly linked list

Tags: c++

Here is my code, and its only swaps correctly once. If I call the swap function more than one times then it doesnt swap correctly.

```
CDoublyLinkedList& CDoublyLinkedList::swapNode(int index1, int index2) // the two nodes at given indices
{
    if (index1 < 0) index1 = 0;
    if (index1 >= count) index1 = count - 1;
    if (index2 < 0) index2 = 0;
    if (index2 >= count) index2 = count - 1;
    if (index2 < index1)
    {
        int tempIndex = index1;
        index1 = index2;
        index2 = tempIndex;
    }
    if (index1 == index2)
    {
        return *this;
    }


    setPosition(index1);
    Node* ptr1 = current;
    setPosition(index2);
    Node* ptr2 = current;
    setPosition();

    // The problem is in the code below this comment

    Node* tempPrevNext;
    Node* tempNextPrev;
    Node* tempPrev;
    Node* tempNext;

    tempPrevNext = ptr1->prev->next;
    tempNextPrev = ptr1->next->prev;
    tempPrev = ptr1->prev;
    tempNext = ptr1->next;

    ptr1->prev->next = ptr2->prev->next;
    ptr1->next->prev = ptr2->next->prev;
    ptr1->prev = ptr2->prev;
    ptr1->next = ptr2->next;

    ptr2->prev->next = tempPrevNext;
    ptr2->next->prev = tempNextPrev;
    ptr2->prev = tempPrev;
    ptr2->next = tempNext;

    return *this;
}
```

At the end all the pointers of both the nodes should be switched but this only works once. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this isnt right  if (index1 >= count) index1 = count - 1 - if index1 == count then you are 1 off the end. You mean  if (index1 > count) index1 = count - 1;

Comment: Just to add the above comment, `if index1 == count == 0`, then you set index1 to -1

Comment: Index correction works exactly the way I wrote it, that part is perfect. the only part is in the swapping

Comment: Could you give us a  [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It would save a lot of time and guesswork.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the pointer swapping, except possibly handling the first and last elements if you're not terminating the list with some kind of sentinel at each end.

Comment: Your error is elsewhere, in code that you aren't showing. **However**, that you are using constructs such as `tempPrevNext = ptr1->prev->next;` is a big red flag. Is your list circular? If not, you shouldn't be doing `ptr1->prev->next`. If it is circular, and if your structure truly is a doubly-linked list, then `ptr1->prev->next` **has** to be `ptr1` (and the same goes for `ptr1->next->prev`). This is an invariant.

Comment: You could reduce the number of compares by using `unsigned int` instead of `signed int`.  The compiler will make sure that an `unsigned int` value is always greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: This is another excellent case for using a debugger.  With the debugger you can *watch* the pointer variables and verify they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but i suspect your bug occurs if you are swapping either the first or last element of your list. that's because you never update your 'head' node to point to a different item, so if you swap the first element, it's new position will be treated as the head.

also, is your array circular? `ptr1->prev->next` should throw a null reference exception for the first element of your list.

if it helps, you can also clean up your code by getting rid of `tempPrevNext` and `tempNextPrev`. 
The important thing to remember is that `ptr1->prev->next` should be `ptr1` before the switch and `ptr2` after.

```
ptr1->prev->next = ptr2;
ptr1->next->prev = ptr2;
ptr2->prev->next = ptr1;
ptr2->next->prev = ptr1;
```

also, is there a reason you want index1 to be smaller than index2? there shouldn't be a reason to switch them, unless your 'setposition' is more efficient if your indices are in order.

Comment: I know about the first and last element, this code is just for the elements in between. I'm trying to make this work, then I would move on to consider the first and last nodes.

Comment: well it's hard to work out what's wrong without seeing what your test input and resultant output is. also, it'd be helpful to see how you define your 'Node.'

Comment: also, if you know about first and last element, why not state that in your original post. I think what everyone has been telling you is the problem is NOT in the code you identified, but no one can help you without more information. comments like 'that part is perfect,' are not helpful, especially when that is far from the case.

Answer (score 0):

Everything below the comment looks right.  Are you sure ptr1 and ptr2 are being set correctly?  I don't see where "current" is being set.  Is is a global var being set by setPosition()?